# How to get all the string in field in MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

Here's my code

```
    public List<String> getListItem() {
    try {
        PreparedStatement ps = Main.getPlugin().sql.getConnection().prepareStatement("SELECT Name FROM textures");
        ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
        
        List<String> l = new ArrayList<>();
        
        while(rs.next()) {
            l.add(rs.getString("Name"));
            return l;
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

and this is how i call it

```
for (String a : utils.getListItem()) {
    cs.sendMessage(a);
}
```

But it just show the first row. I have search for this for like 2 days and nothing make my code work. Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place your return statement outside while loop. If you put `return` statement within while loop it will return the list after first iteration and skip remaining.

```
while(rs.next()) {
   l.add(rs.getString("Name"));
}
return l;
```